# Can you expand a real scalar field $\phi(t,\mathbf{x})$ in terms of spherical harmonics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, fourier-transform, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

A massless real scalar admits the expansion
$$
\phi(t,\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^{3/2} \sqrt{2|\mathbf{p}|}} \bigg( e^{ - i |\mathbf{p}| t + i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} } a_{\mathbf{p}} 
 + e^{+ i |\mathbf{p}| t - i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} } a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\ast} \bigg)
$$
which when quantized has ladder operators which satisfy $[a_{\mathbf{p}},a_{\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}] = \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{k})$ as well as $[a_{\mathbf{p}},a_{\mathbf{k}}] =[a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\ast},a_{\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}]  = 0$. These are expanded in terms of a plane-wave basis.

Is it possible to expand the field in a basis of angular momentum states? The Klein-Gordon equation in spherical coordinates is a product of spherical Bessel functions and spherical harmonics which makes me think these will be involved. Is there some set of different ladder operators $b_{|\mathbf{p}|,\ell,m}$ corresponding to various angular momentum states (*i.e.* probably being labelled by $|\mathbf{p}|$, $\ell$ and $m$ and so on)?

Schematically, I imagine something like
$$
\phi(t,\mathbf{x}) \sim \int d|\mathbf{p}| \sum_{\ell,m} \bigg( e^{ - i |\mathbf{p}| t} j_{\ell}(|\mathbf{p}r|) Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi) b_{|\mathbf{p}|,\ell,m} 
 + \text{h.c.} \bigg)
$$

Comment: Definitely, this is precisely what people mean by the [orbital angular momentum of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light). You can see a version of this at the level of the $S$-matrix in section 3.7 of Weinberg QFT, volume 1.

Comment: Yes, and $b$'s and $a$'s are related by Bogoliubov transforms. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation

Comment: This is also very common in some other spacetimes. In Hawking's derivation of particle creation by black holes he uses a decomposition like that (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103899181). This is also quite common when quantizing fields in ${\rm AdS}$ spacetime in global coordinates (https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01040).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can expand any object in any basis you want, this is precisely the point of bases. Whether a given basis is *useful* or not is an entirely different question. In flat space $\mathbb R^n$ the basis of plane waves is the most convenient one because it diagonalizes translations, which is a massive simplification. I cannot think of any situation where your spherical-harmonics basis is more useful than the plane-wave basis, but it is certainly a valid expansion.

Indeed, the integrand
$$
f(x,\vec p):=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{2|\vec p|}}e^{ipx}a_{\vec p}
$$
is a certain function of $\vec p$, and you can express it in spherical coordinates and expand it in spherical harmonics:
$$
f(x,r,\theta,\phi)=\sum_{\ell,m}q_{\ell,m}(x,r)Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)
$$
where
$$
q_{\ell,m}(x,r):=\int f(x,r,\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)^*\mathrm d\Omega
$$

You can plug this into your plane-wave expansion for $\phi$,
$$
\phi(x)=\int f(x,\vec p)\mathrm d\vec p+\text{c.c}
$$
and simplify the $\theta,\phi$ integration somewhat but, again, this is in virtually any situation a step back, unless you have a very specific application in mind.

The plane-wave expansion is the most convenient expression for this problem. Other expansions are mathematically valid but almost invariably useless.

---

When spacetime is not flat, you generically do not have translations anymore, in which case there is no point in diagonalizing them -- they are not a symmetry of your problem. In general you want to expand in the simplest, largest (abelian) isometry subgroup. If you have a curved manifold with spherical symmetry but no translation symmetry, then it definitely starts making sense expanding in spherical harmonics. And this is indeed a common technique in QFT in curved spacetime. But this goes beyond the original question in the OP so I don't have much more to say here.

Comment: Situations with rotational symmetry but no transnational symmetry aren't that rare. I have used this type of expansion when considering impurities in a many body system

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That makes sense. Just to confirm: It is wrong to assume that the ladder operators are different here, correct? Meaning $b = a$ in my question above?

Comment: @QuantumEyedea $a$ and $b$ are linearly related, but the precise coefficient requires  evaluating the integrals carefully, which I have not done. There might be e.g. factors of $2\pi$ or so.

Comment: It seems that in your answer $r,\theta, \phi$ are spherical coordinates in momentum space, while I think in the question they are spherical coordinate in space. This is why in the author formula $\phi$ depends on them while you are integrating over. It is indeed hard also for me to imagine a situation where your expansion is useful, while the one in the original post can be, if you are preserving rotation but not traslation, This is why he was using spherical coordinates in space, not in momentum.

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci Is this related to monopole scattering?

Comment: What do you mean? I am just saying that what you wrote is not an answer to the author's question.

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci Yes yes I'm just wondering if this is ultimately the same confusion as the recent discussion of whether it makes sense to ascribe a particle interpretation to the defect Hilbert space of a 0-form in 4d...